# Assembly printf - only prints first character of string

Tags: string, assembly, printf

I am trying to print a string in assembly by calling printf.

My assembly code:

```
mov dword[ebx + 0], '"'
mov dword[ebx + 4], 'h'
mov dword[ebx + 8], 'e'
mov dword[ebx + 12], 'l'
mov dword[ebx + 16], 'l'
mov dword[ebx + 20], 'o'
mov dword[ebx + 24], '"'
mov dword[ebx + 28], 0
push ebx
push formatString
call printf
add esp, 8
...
formatString    db    '%s', 10, 0
```

However when I run this it only prints the first character - '"', not the whole word ("hello").

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My assembly is rusty, but those should probably be byte-wise moves.  You need a byte array in memory since that is what `printf` is expecting for a `%s`.  The string in memory is probably `"\0\0\0h\0\0\0e\0\0\0l\0\0\0l\0\0\0o\0\0\0"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`.

```
mov dword[ebx + 0], '"'        ; moves the 32-bit value 0x22000000 to EBX
mov dword[ebx + 4], 'h'        ; moves the 32-bit value 0x68000000 to EBX + 4
...
```

So, if `ebx` contains the address 0x123456, then you would have something like the following in memory:

```
0123456 | 22 00 00 00  68 00 00 00   65 00 00 00  6c 00 00 00 | "...h...e...l... |
0123466 | 6c 00 00 00  6f 00 00 00   22 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 | l...o..."....... |
```

Even though you are passing 0x123456 into `printf` as the address, it is only seeing a single character before it hits the first NUL byte.  The following should work:

```
mov dword[ebx + 0], 577267052   ; 0x2268656c = "hel
mov dword[ebx + 4], 1819222528  ; 0x6c6f2200 = lo"\0
push ebx
push formatString
call printf
add esp, 8
```

There is probably a much better way to load bytes into an indirect address based on `ebx` but I haven't looked at assembly in more years than I can count.

Comment: But isn't the 2nd parameter to printf just expecting a char *, which is what I am giving in ebx?

Comment: Yes.  `ebx` is the address of a *byte array* in memory.  The problem is that you are loading a series of `dword`s into memory.